# How to get the IP address for remote host using Java

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming

I need to get the IP address for remote hosts. I tried the following and works fine:

```
socket = factory.createSocket(hostName, port);  
InetAddress remoteIP = socket.getInetAddress();
String[] remoteIPOnly = remoteIP.toString().split("\\/");
System.out.println("Remote IP is: "+remoteIPOnly[1]);
```

But, I need a way where I don't have to specify a port number. I.e, I need the IP for a remote host despite the port number. Is this possible ? Is it possible to get the IP without creating socket from the first place ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `getHostAddress()` as below:

```
    InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName("www.google.com");
    String ipAddress = inetAddress.getHostAddress();
    System.out.println(ipAddress );//prints 66.152.109.61
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName("www.google.com");
byte[] raw = inetAddress.getAddress();
```

The byte array now contains the IP addresses bytes.